# Display latest x posts from all categories using a custom taxonomy (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I am attempting to display the latest x posts from all categories using a custom taxonomy called 'case-studies' in WordPress.

I have managed to output all the category names as heading links I have also outputted some posts below each category but they are all the same, I need a way to filter the post output by the category, see PHP comments below for details.

```
             <?php if (have_posts()) : 

                $tax = 'case-studies';

                $cat_args = array(
                  'orderby' => 'name',
                  'order' => 'ASC'
                );

                $categories = get_terms($tax, $cat_args); 

                foreach($categories as $category) {

                    echo '<p><a href="' . get_term_link( $category, $tax ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a></p>';

                    // Post output is not working, outputs all posts using case-studies taxonomy for each category, I need a way to filter this query by category, 'category' => $category->term_id does not work, nor does 'category' => $category
                    $post_args = array(
                        'posts_per_page' => 10,
                        'post_type' => 'case-studies'
                    );

                    $posts = get_posts($post_args);

                    foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a><br/>
                    <?php }

                    echo '<p><a href="' . get_term_link( $category, $tax ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>View all posts in ' . $category->name.'</a></p>';
                }

            endif; ?>
```

Comment: Functions such as `the_permalink` and `the_title` only work within what in WP terms is called “The Loop” – you can’t expect them to produce correct output when using your own `foreach` loop constructs instead. If you are unfamiliar with how The Loop works, then please go read up on it: https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: @CBroe They also work when using [setup_postdata()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata)

Comment: I have fixed $category->term_id issue by replacing this with $category. Now just need to fix the post output. As for being in the loop - this is in my loop-case-studies.php file.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden: Right … but I don’t see that being used here anywhere either.

Comment: This is inside my loop, do you mean I need to add  <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>  <?php endif; ?> around my code? I have tried replacing the title with <?php echo get_the_title(); ?> but this doesn't work either, I don't think I am getting any output through the query. Maybe a code example would help.

Comment: My code has been updated, the heading links now work and I have it outputting ALL posts under each category, I just don't know how to filter the output by category in $post_args